# If $R$ is transitive, then $R^+$ exists. In fact, $R^+ = R$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> If $R$ is transitive, then $R^+$ exists. In fact, $R^+ = R$.

So for this question. I was wondering If I had the correct approach. My thinking went like this:
Suppose $R$ is transitive.

$R^+$ means it is the smallest transitive x that contains $R$ as a subset.
By definition, $R^+$ is the smallest transitive of $R$.
It contains itself as a subset.
So therefore, $R^+ = R$.

Comment: Just to be crystal clear here: $R$ is a (binary) relation?

Comment: In this content $R^+$ is usually called the *transitive closure* of $R$.

Comment: Well yes, it means its the transitive closure of R. But I mean, that transitive closure means a subset smallest transitive x that contains R as a subset.

Answer (score 3):

The idea you present is in spirit correct, but you need to write more precisely. For instance you write

> $R^{+}$ means it is the smallest transitive x that contains R as a subset

but probably mean "$R^{+}$ is the smallest transitive **relation** on the **set** $X$ that contains $R$ as a subset".

> By definition, $R^{+}$ is the smallest transitive of $R$

means exactly the same thing as that which you wrote in the previous sentence. And by continuing with

> It contains itself as a subset.

You are only saying that "$R^{+}$ contains itself as a subset" which is probably not what you wanted to say but this in turn does not justify the punchline $R^{+}=R$.

As such it is difficult to judge the correctness of what you have written.

---

If I were to write up the idea which I think you are trying to convey it would be:

Suppose that $R$ is a transitive relation on a set $X$. By definition, $R^{+}$ is the smallest transitive relation on $X$ that contains $R$ as a subset. Since $R$ is a transitive relation on $X$ that contains $R$, $R^{+}\subseteq R$. Then we get $R\subseteq R^{+}\subseteq R$ so $R^{+} = R$.